# Android, Half scroll then float

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, scroll

I need to create Android layout similar to Instagram Android app using Vertical `LinearLayout` consisting of `ImageView` (please refer to the attached diagram) that is fixed height, "SomeView" (fixed height), and lastly `ListView` or `WebView` that will occupy all vertical space regardless content size.

This layout can be scrolled vertically, but after scrolling up and the `ImageView` becomes out of sight, the "SomeView" component need to float at the top of the screen, and only the `ListView` remains scrollable.

In this state, when the user scroll down the `ListView` until the top item in it appears, the `ImageView` will reappear at the top followed by "SomeView" (it will no longer float), returning to the original layout.

Any ideas on what Android component or examples I should look at? Thanks so much.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: the link is not working..

Comment: thanks for your edit, and image confirmation, sorry i change it to stack image, you should able to see it now

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at sticky headers [like this](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) or you could also try the [StickyScrollView](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems) to start tagging views you want to stick to the top.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, ill check it ASAP. 

still open for more ideas